# Preencher input de acordo com o select

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Preciso que quando selecione algo no select faça uma chamada no banco de dados pelo ajax e retorne.
O problema que nada acontece.

Esse é o script do Index o JavaScript:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

var idsubcategoria = $("select#idsubcategoria").val();
  $('#idsubcategoria').change(function(){
                //O método $.ajax(); é o responsável pela requisição
                $.ajax
                        ({
                            //Configurações
                            type: 'POST',//Método que está sendo utilizado.
                            dataType: 'html',//É o tipo de dado que a página vai retornar.
                            url: 'nomes.php',//Indica a página que está sendo solicitada.
                            //função que vai ser executada assim que a requisição for enviada
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
                            },
                           data: {idsubcategoria: idsubcategoria},//Dados para consulta
                           //função que será executada quando a solicitação for finalizada.
                           success: function (msg)
                            {
                                $("#dados").html(msg);
                            }
                        });

  }); 
});

</script>
```

Esse é o select que preciso de que quando a pessoa selecione faça a chamada no mysqli.

```html
<select name="idsubcategoria" class="idsubcategoria" id="idsubcategoria" required="required">
<option value="">Escolha...</option>
</select>
```

Esse é o input que quero que receba a resposta.

```html
<input type="text" id="dados" required="required">
```

No arquivo nomes.php eu coloquei assim como teste para ver se ia ter retorno.

```html
<?
$palavra = $_POST['idsubcategoria'];

 echo $palavra;

?>
```

Comment: A linha `var idsubcategoria = $("select#idsubcategoria").val();` é corrida antes do select mudar. Estás sempre a enviar o mesmo valor, inicial, para o servidor... Coloca essa linha dentro do change pelo menos.

Comment: @Sergio
Fiz a alteração que falou e acrescentei uma div para receber ao invés do input e a div está recebendo, mais o input nada de receber a informação, pode me ajudar com isso.

Comment: @Sergio
Consegui depois da sua dica tomei outros rumos e fiz uma modificação trocando:
Essa linha: $("#dados").html(msg);
Por Essa linha: document.cal2.dados.value = msg;

Caso tenha uma outra maneira de ser feita por favor coloque aqui.

Comment: Em vez de `$("#dados").html(msg); ` deves ter `$("#dados").val(msg); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dois problemas:

- A linha `var idsubcategoria = $("select#idsubcategoria").val();` é corrida antes do select mudar. Estás sempre a enviar o mesmo valor, o inicial, para o servidor... Coloca essa linha dentro do change pelo menos, mas podias usar o `this.value` que é o valor do select dentro do `.change(`.
- Para mudar o valor de um input deves usar o `.val(` e não o `.html(`

Assim o teu código poderia ser:

```js
 $(function() {
    $('#idsubcategoria').change(function() {
    const idsubcategoria = this.value;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', //Método que está sendo utilizado.
        dataType: 'html', //É o tipo de dado que a página vai retornar.
        url: 'nomes.php', //Indica a página que está sendo solicitada.
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
        },
        data: {idsubcategoria: idsubcategoria},
        success: function(msg) {
          $("#dados").val(msg);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```